# How to implement array_filter() to make more clear

Tags: php, symfony

I need a little help in the PHP, because I'm trying to use the `array_filter()` to prevent to many lines and make it simply and clear, but I'm struggling in this one, even if I'm reading this documentation: [Array_Filter](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php) so I need a correct way to implement, because sometimes the `getCategoryTree()` comes empty or with null values, which I'm trying to not show it, I thought to create other function to show only specific things without category, but I feel that it is not efficient:

What I'm trying is to populate from the url www.foobar.com/checkout/payments, and this is the original code:

```
$page['eData'] = [
    'codeMoneyFormatter' => $this->moneyFormatter->getcodeMoneyFormatter(),
    'checkout' => [
        'actionField' => ['step' => 3, 'option' => 'Review Order'],
        // ---------------- THIS ONE MUST REFACTOR -------
        'products' => $this->getCartFromOrder($order),
    ],
];

// --------------------- REFACTOR ------------------
$itemData['category'] = $category ? $this->getCategoryTree($category->getId()) : '';
// -------------------------------------------------
```

This function is where it shows the category, but I don't like it because at all, because in some pages it comes empty/null which it's not correct, so I want to use the `array_filter()`

```
// --------------------- ARRAY_FILTER ------------------
$itemData['category'] = array_filter($category ? $this->getCategoryTree($category->getId()) : '');
// -------------------------------------------------
```

The function that I created to show only specific thing, it's correct because it does not show the category, but I feel that it's unnecessary because its repeating the same from the original one:

```
$page['eData'] = [
    'codeMoneyFormatter' => $this->moneyFormatter->getcodeMoneyFormatter(),
    'checkout' => [
        'actionField' => ['step' => 3, 'option' => 'Review Order'],
        'products' => $this->getCheckoutFromOrder($order),
    ],
];
```

It's repeating almost the same functions and it's not the correct standard of DRY (Don't repeat yourself) that's why I thought to implement the `array_filter()` but how???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Array_Filter so I need a correct way to implement, because sometimes the getCategoryTree() comes empty or with null values

Easy, don't change types and feed array filter something it shouldn't eat.

```
 array_filter($category ? $this->getCategoryTree($category->getId()) : '');
```

Should be (something like)

```
 $data = $category ? $this->getCategoryTree($category->getId()) : [];
 if(!is_array($data)) $data = [];

 array_filter($data);
```

You can probably do it simpler then this. But, type changes in PHP can be troublesome because the language is loosely typed and won't complain to much.

This can be easly tested

```
var_dump(array_filter(''));
```

output

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
NULL
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da273ea464682d8837af0f520ab96d56a26062f4)

This on the other hand

```
 var_dump(array_filter([]));
```

Simply returns an empty array.

The last thing I will say is about 80% of the code you put in the question was unnecessary to answer the question and just serves to confuse other users.